# How to make an excel sheet untouchable?

Tags: excel, vba

how can i make an excel sheet untouchable? i mean, i want to move to the 'sheet3' when i press 'sheet2>'. the jpg attached.
thanks in advance!

[image: excel sheet]

Comment: Hi Elshan, welcome to Stack Overflow.  It is unclear from your question what you're trying to ask.  Can you clarify what you're attempting to achieve?

Comment: Have you tried anything? There is a worksheet activate event.

Comment: You can just hide it..

Comment: You could hide it and password protect it, but it can be unhidden and Excel passwords are pretty easy to break. The only guaranteed way to make it _untouchable_ is to remove it (and put it in a different spreadsheet that the user hasn't got access to).

Answer (score 1):

Put the following code in your `ThisWorkbook` scope:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Workbook_SheetActivate(ByVal Sh As Object)
    If Right$(Sh.Name, 1) = ">" And Sh.Index + 1 <= ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Count Then
         ThisWorkbook.Sheets(Sh.Index + 1).Activate
    End If
End Sub
```

and it will move to the next sheet when ever the sheet name ends with `>`

**But I recommend to hide `sheet2>` instead of doing this.** What you try is playing around but not secure at all.